# Flutter ios: I'm getting "(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)", can't see why

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, flutter-ios

I'm new to flutter and I've received a "working Android" project which I should adapt to iOS, at least I need it to make it boot and such.

After some reading here and there and then some additional googling I've come with a version of the flutter app that Xcode 13 can compile and launch on the simulator without any problem, but once it runs then some kind of initialization process fails with this error:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
```

I read the words of the message, I understand what they say but I don't understand what they mean.

I already did a `flutter clean` a `flutter pub get` then I went into the `ios` folder to do a pod install/update. Typically I delete Pods folder just in case (to have a even cleaner environment)...

The pubspec.yaml relevant lines I have are these:

```
name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  firebase_crashlytics: "^2.2.3"
  airship_flutter: ^4.0.0
  pull_to_refresh: 2.0.0
  http: ^0.13.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^0.2.8

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/splash.png
  android: true
  ios: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

After doing pod install/update I also get this relevant info inside my Podfile.lock file:

```
Airship (14.4.2):
Airship/Automation (14.4.2):
Airship/Core (14.4.2)
Airship/ExtendedActions (14.4.2):
Airship/MessageCenter (14.4.2):
airship_flutter (4.4.0):
Firebase/CoreOnly (8.9.0):
Firebase/Crashlytics (8.9.0):
firebase_core (1.10.0):
firebase_crashlytics (2.3.0):
FirebaseCore (8.9.0):
FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (8.9.0):
FirebaseCrashlytics (8.9.0):
FirebaseInstallations (8.9.0):
Flutter (1.0.0)
GoogleDataTransport (9.1.2):
GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.6.0):
GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.6.0):
GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.6.0):
nanopb (2.30908.0):
nanopb/decode (2.30908.0)
nanopb/encode (2.30908.0)
PromisesObjC (2.0.0)
airship_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/airship_flutter/ios`)
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
firebase_crashlytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`)
Flutter (from `Flutter`)
```

(I got this simplified version executing this command line: `cat ios/Podfile.lock  | grep " - " | grep "(" | grep -v "   "`

EDIT: I did some 'flutter pub upgrade' to raise my libraries versions a bit. The versions of the above list are the last ones I'm using.

EDIT: Here I add also some excerpt from my lib/main.dart file

```
...
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // This is for Firebase
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  HttpOverrides.global = PolarStarHttpOverrides();

  // Launch app after splash
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final Future<FirebaseApp> _fbApp = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: _fbApp,
...
```

I'm not sure about what else to look for, Xcode builds ok, min SDK version is set to 11, the app builds, but it doesn't go beyond some ugly banner on screen claiming "Something went WORNG" (sic)

This error appears in some other people's Stack Overflow questions but for Android, and I'm using iOS. My coworker (using android) has no apparent problem whatsoever booting and running the flutter app.

I've read documentation here and there, but nothing has lead me to any relevant fix...

Is there some additional detail I might have overlooked?

EDIT: I've already tried many different cleaning approaches (as running "flutter clean" and some other similar commands for the "ios" subproject ) to no avail. I also tried some "flutter pub upgrade" (instead of 'get') in case some newer version libraries could appear (and some of them did, but to no avail again).

Comment: do you have a google plist file

Comment: Yep, some GoogleService-Info.plist with all kind of funny hashes and IDs inside... (correctly assigned to the flutter target)

Answer (score 0):

Add `firebase_core :any` in pubspec.yaml, delete `PodFile.lock` Run flutter clean then flutter pub get. Then navigate to ios folder in terminal. Run pod install. Now you should be able to run it successfully.

Comment: I would say I've unsuccessfully tried it many times before (except for the "firebase_core: any" part)... I will try it again just because of this detail...

Comment: As expected, it failed again... The app builds perfectly, but in runtime it doesn't manage to pass the "missing plugin exception"

Comment: Did you try to run this from xcode too?

Comment: I've tried particularly running it under "Xcode + RUN ", but now you tell me I've just tried "flutter run --no-sound-null-safety" and the same error message appears: [  +59 ms] flutter: You have an error! MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)

Comment: Can you post main.dart code too please? The firebase init part would suffice too

Comment: Yep, I added an additional edit to my main question.

Comment: await Firebase.initializeApp();. I don't see this in your app. Can you check the initialisation codes please?

Comment: I'm not sure where I can find this init code you say... in the main.dart file? I've looked for "await Firebase.initializeApp()" all over the lib folder (with a nice 'grep' ) and it doesn't appear at all... So I understand I should add it somewhere (in the main.dart file?)

Comment: OTOH, the snippet I pasted already has a Firebase.initializeApp() but without an "await", I assume I should change (or adapt) the one I had for the other you suggest...

Comment: Did it work now please?

Comment: I added the await  line right after the ensureinitialized line, in main(), and same thing happens (same xcode output error, but with 'asynchoronus something' in front of the error line, in xcode log). I didn't replace one for the other, I just added your line in my main (keeping my original one in place)...
I'm not really proficient in the .dart part of flutter so maybe some of your (apparently trivial) suggestions don't come as understandable to me...

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/

Comment: I had already followed all these steps, got my ID's, plists, read about the await thing etc... But the thing is I've received some legacy (working) Android-flutter code that (ideally) shouldn't be needed to be refactored. I could of course refactor everything according to the official docs, but then the already working implemented Android solution would stop working, or the Android team wouldn't approve my changes. Of course, the Android "working" solution might be all wrong and actually need said refactor, but then it's something that needs to be discussed with them. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove podfile.lock,.symlinks, Pods
Now "flutter pub get" & install pods using "pod install"
after that  just open  XCode again..**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).